# Visibility Hidden in IE8 using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am facing a problem with javascript in ie8. Iam hiding an element using this syntax.

```
document.getElementById("<%=fnl000Db000Tran000PERIODTYPE_ID000Value000PERIOD_TYPE_DESC.ClientId %>").style.visibility = false
```

I Used

```
 document.getElementById("<%=fnl000Db000Tran000PERIODTYPE_ID000Value000PERIOD_TYPE_DESC.ClientId %>").style.visibility = "hidden"
```

But no use. It showing an error: something like Expected; 
but i used semicolons at every end of the line.

Comment: Please check it once. I have dot in my script but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a dot:

```
getElementById("id").style
```

Other than that, it's definitely a [string value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so your second code snippet is correct in that aspect. But it's missing a semicolon. Although technically that is not required in JavaScript, you can try adding a semicolon directly before and after the statement to see if that helps:

```
;document.getElementById("").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Finally, try this link in IE8 and compare it with your own code: http://jsfiddle.net/4szBA/1/

Comment: typing mistake here. But I got dot in my script

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `.` after your obscenely long ID and close parenthesis, and before `style`.

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
document.getElementById("...")style.visibility = "hidden";
```

you *should* use

```
document.getElementById("...").style.visibility = "hidden";
//----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dot in front of `style.visibility`